# How do I rewire 2 different switches controlling 2 different lights so that each switch is a 3-way switch controlling both lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring

**Current situation:** I have two regular switches (SW1 & SW2) and two ceiling lights (L1 & L2) in a long hallway, and each switch controls one of the lights. So SW1 controls L1, and SW2 controls L2.

**Desired situation:** I would like to rewire so that I can control ***both*** lights L1 & L2 with ***either*** SW1 or SW2.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: How do you feel about smart switches?  As compared with how do you feel about drywalling?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, Peter. There are many possible ways your current wiring could be configured, and you haven't told us what you're willing to do to complete this project.

Comment: @ Harper  Haven't really worked with smart switches, but can do some simple drywalling if necessay

Comment: @isherwood What additional information is needed? I am happy to provide. Each light switch has a different breaker switch in the breaker switch box if that helps...

Comment: Are you comfortable replacing *all* the wires between the two switch boxes?

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel The two switches are on opposite ends of the hall, so in order to connect them together, I would need to run wire from SW1 up to the ceiling, then across attic on top of ceiling to other end of hall, then drop down to SW2. Yes, I think I can do this.

Comment: Conceptually, below is the way I understand it. Do I have it right?

Comment: I already have power coming into SW1. So could I just simply then run a traveler wire from SW1 to SW2?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the two lights stay on their respective circuits, or is putting both lights on one circuit an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks, and sorry for the late reply. It's not a requirement that both lights stay on their respective circuits; putting both lights on the same circuit is an option. Whatever is easiest.

Comment: Can you pull out the switches and lights (leaving wires connected) and take well-lit pictures of the wiring inside the boxes, and post them here? Turn off the breaker(s) first if you're not comfortable doing that with the power on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have accepted the idea of having to rewire the circuit and change out the switches to 3-ways. Then here is the wiring schematic for a source coming in the first switch.
[image]

You do have to parallel the two lights together. That's the only thing that is not shown.

Good luck

Comment: Many thanks for the wiring diagram, and sorry for the late response! I'll give this a try and report back once I'm finished.